# Достать только id из строки со скобками

Tags: python

Мне нужно достать id из строки `601 ДАГАХ ( 45487 )`. id - это то что в скобках в конце строки `( 45487 )`, но так же есть вот такие строки `МРС-086(ПРИМ) ( 18893 )`, `МРС-086(ПРИМ4343) ( 18893 )`.
Так вот, как я могу достать только нужные мне данные?

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'МРС-086(ПРИМ4343) ( 18893 )'
print(s[s.rfind('(') + 1:s.rfind(')')-1].strip())
```

Костыль, конечно, лучше через регулярку, что-то типа:

```
import re
s = '601 ДАГАХ ( 45487 )'
r = re.search(r"\((\s\d+\s)\)", s)
print(r[0][1:-1].strip())
```

Comment: лучше использовать такое регулярное выражение ```r"\([\d ]*\)"``` на тот случай если между скобками не будет пробелов

Comment: А `strip` зачем? Получайте сразу результат из регулярки `re.search("\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)",s)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

конкретно для таких строк как приведены в вопросе сработает обычный сплит:

```
text = '601 ДАГАХ ( 45487 )'
id_ = text.split()[-2]  # '45487'
```